# How to move multiple objects in relation to central point

Tags: modeling, mesh

What I mean precisely is how to move multiple objects away from central point without scaling them.

This is what I'm working with:
[image: half a cylinder separated into triangles]

I'm searching for a way to create little space between the triangles. All triangles are separate objects.

Or if you can do this with scaling that's ok too ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

In the header of the 3D window change the pivot point from median point (default) to "individual origins", then select all objects and scale.

[image]

Comment: with the given information above i have done but its working in different manner. Is there any other step that messing  http://pasteall.org/pic/index.php?id=119115

Comment: You scaled in edit mode a single mesh with every triangle joined to the others, while the question was about many triangles as separate objects.

Comment: In this latter situation, select all edges in edit mode, then press "Ctrl E  - edge split", so that every triangle will be "isolated", then it will work.